# Azure Pipelines local PostgreSQL server on agent

Tags: postgresql, azure-devops

I've started using Azure Pipelines, and my django application runs tests which require a local PostgreSQL server.

I'm pretty stumped as I cannot find any information in the MS documentation for how to change the agents configuration to include a local PostgreSQL server.

It seems like a very simple thing to do but I cannot seem to find the relevant documentation. Looking at the agent pool information it lists MySQL as being installed locally.

How can I include a local PostgreSQL server in the configuration of the agent that will build my application and run tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

- Create a Docker container with your testing prerequisites in it, and then run your tests in the container
- Create your own self-hosted agent and install whatever software you need on it, and then use that instead of the Microsoft-hosted agents.

Comment: A docker container with testing requirements was the way to go.